# JQuery table manipulation issues

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table that displays events of a certain location (in this example, Madrid) from the last.fm API. I am able to get the data with AJAX, but the problem is the table filling is awkward, in the way that the header is placed at the bottom of the table.

Here's my JQuery:

```
$.fn.getEvents = function(location) {
    var onComplete = function() {
      //$('#eventtbl').jExpand();
      $('#evttbldiv').fadeIn(250);
    };

    var $this = $(this);

    var container = $this.html();

    this.each(function() {
       $.getJSON(
        settings.PHP_REQUEST_URL,
        {
          method    : "geo.getEvents",
          api_key   : settings.LASTFM_APIKEY,
          location  : location,
          distance  : settings.MAX_DISTANCE,
          format    : "json"
        },
        function(data) {
          $.each(data.events.event, function(i, item){
            event     = item.title;
            headliner = item.artists.headliner;
            venue     = item.venue.name;
            date      = item.startDate;

            if(i != 0) $('.headers', $this).remove();
            $this.append(container);

            var $current = $this.children(':eq('+i+')');

            $current.find('[class=lfm_event]').append(event);
            $current.find('[class=lfm_headliner]').append(headliner);
            $current.find('[class=lfm_venue]').append(venue);
            $current.find('[class=lfm_date]').append(date);

            if(i == (settings.MAX_TRACKS - 1)){
              onComplete.call(this);
          }
          });
        }
      );
  });
};
```

Here's my table HTML:

```
<div id="evttbldiv">
      <table id="eventtbl">
          <tr class="headers">
            <th>Evento</th>
            <th>Artista principal</th>
            <th>Local</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        <tr class="rowdata">
          <td class="lfm_event"></td>
          <td class="lfm_headliner"></td>
          <td class="lfm_venue"></td>
          <td class="lfm_date"></td>
          <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowinfo">
            <td colspan="5">
              hello
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

And here's how I invoke the method:

```
  $('#eventtbl').getEvents('madrid');
```

You can see the page live [here](http://phpdev.dei.isep.ipp.pt/i101524/lastfm-widget/index.html).

What I'd like to happen is have the header at the top, and when I grab the data with `$this = $(this)`, it grabs the header as well. Is there any way to keep the header intact and just inject each row of the table after the header? With my current code, I'm getting the entire table and then removing the header if it's not the first row, which seems pretty inefficient and it ends up messing up my table, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .after() function:

```
$(header).after(the_html);
```

Hope that helps

Edit:

You could use:

```
$("#yourtable tr:last-child").append(the_html);
```

Comment: So basically I don't grab the entire table, just the parts after the header, and then after getting all the data, I inject the HTML after the header? But what happens if it's the second row, then it would have to be injected after the first row that isn't the header, right?

Comment: Yeah, you would have to store the last eow object to call the append function on this. I am thinking about a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to set up your table with a `thead` and `tbody`

```
<div id="evttbldiv">
    <table id="eventtbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Evento</th>
                <th>Artista principal</th>
                <th>Local</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="rowdata">
                <td class="lfm_event"></td>
                <td class="lfm_headliner"></td>
                <td class="lfm_venue"></td>
                <td class="lfm_date"></td>
                <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowinfo">
                <td colspan="5">
                    hello
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then you would have to split out the header data from the row data.

```
$('table')
    .find('thead').html(header).end()
    .find('tbody').html(container);
```